# Simple proof by induction: $1^3 + 2^3 +3^3 +...+ n^3 = [ (n(n+1))/2 ]^2 $

Tags: summation, induction

I am rather illiterate when it comes to mathematics, I am afraid. In an effort to change that, I grabbed a copy of 'What is mathematics? : An elementary approach to ideas and methods' and have already encountered some difficulty. It seems silly to waste so much time trying to solve it myself, so I decided to ask for some help in solving and illuminating the taken steps, so that I can solve some more on my own. I shall review some of the basics while awaiting answers, and hope that my session tomorrow shall be more productive...

The problem is as follows:

Prove by induction that $1^3 + 2^3 +3^3 ... n^3 = [ (n(n+1))/2 ]^2 $.

As is, at the point I decided to seek help and look up material for review, I have taken the following steps:

solved for the base case: n=1, $1^3 = [2/2]^2 $

$$ 1 = 1^2, 1=1 $$

Then after proving the basis, I stated the assumption that:

$1^3 + 2^3 ... k^3 = [ (k(k+1)) / 2 ]^2$ is true.

Then I tried to solve for the next case, $(k+1)^3$:

$$ 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 ... k^3 + (k+1)^3 = [ ( (k(k+1)) / 2 ) + (k+1) ]^2 $$

$$ [ (k(k+1)) / 2 ]^2  + (k+1)^3   =  [ (k(k+1) + 1(k+1) ) / 2 ]^2 $$

at this point after failing for a while and having spent quite some time looking up material, I sought help. I hope I'm going down the right path here, but I suspect I shall soon find out...

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've come further than most people struggling with induction, so keep at it. At this point it's mostly a matter of multiplying out everything, and just confirm that what is on the right side is the same as what is on the left side. Remember that you don't have to manipulate one of the sides to become equal to the other, you can simplify both sides concurrently and see that you end up with the same thing at the end.

Comment: @user209632 Are you allowed to use the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ in your proof? This is a rather well-known result and proofs of it abound. If you can use this fact, then I have a proof that might help you out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**$$\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2+(k+1)^3=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3$$$$=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3}{4}$$$$=\frac{(k+1)^2(k^2+4(k+1))}{4}$$$$=\frac{(k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)}{4}$$$$=\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$$Hopefully you can complete the proof from here...

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track! The simplest way to show the last line is to foil out the terms on the left and right and note that they're equal (tedious, I know--but it'll get you what you need). If you haven't done so already, try proving these formulas with induction (for extra practice; they're a little easier):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\quad\quad \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

EDIT: And by "last line," I mean the "goal":
$$\left(\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right)^2 + (k+1)^3 = \left(\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to prove the statement $S(n)$ for all $n\geq 1$ where
$$
S(n) : 1^3 + 2^3 +3^3 +\cdots + n^3 = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2.
$$
Using $\Sigma$-notation, we may rewrite $S(n)$ as follows:
$$
S(n) : \sum_{r=1}^n r^3 = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2.
$$
**Base step:** The statement $S(1)$ says that $(1)^3 = (1)^2$ which is true because $1=1$.

**Inductive step [$S(k)\to S(k+1)$]:** Fix some $k\geq 1$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume that
$$
S(k) : \sum_{r=1}^k r^3 = \left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2
$$
holds. To be proved is that
$$
S(k+1) : \sum_{r=1}^{k+1} r^3 = \left[\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}{2}\right]^2
$$
follows. Beginning with the left side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{k+1}r^3 &= \sum_{r=1}^k r^3 + (k+1)^3\tag{evaluate sum for $i=k+1$}\\[1em]
                    &= \left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2+(k+1)^3\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[1em]
                    &= \frac{(k+1)^2}{4}[k^2+4(k+1)]\tag{factor out $\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}$}\\[1em]
                    &= \frac{(k+1)^2}{4}[(k+2)(k+2)]\tag{factor quadratic}\\[1em]
                    &= \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}\tag{multiply and rearrange}\\[1em]
                    &= \left[\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\right]^2\tag{rearrange}\\[1em]
                    &= \left[\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}{2}\right]^2,\tag{rearrange}
\end{align}
one arrives at the right side of $S(k+1)$, thereby showing that $S(k+1)$ is also true, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, it is proved that for all $n\geq 1$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that the statement $S(n)$ is true.

**Note:** The step where $\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{4}$ is factored out is an important one. If we do not factor this out and, instead, choose to expand $(k+1)^3$, the problem becomes much more messy than it needs to be.